# Permissions to create clients on chef-server

Tags: chef-infra, knife

On chef-server I have a group `provisioners` for users who should have permissions to bootstrap and provision nodes so called [validator-less](https://www.chef.io/blog/2015/04/16/validatorless-bootstraps/).

While bootstrapping a machine, knife tries to create new client and node on chef server. Problem is with ACL for that group. In Global Permissions section I can find container and grant `create` permission only for nodes but not for clients. That's why  `knife bootstrap` fails with:

```
Creating new client for node-01
ERROR: You authenticated successfully to https://chef-server:443/organizations/test as mlanin but you are not authorized for this action
Response:  missing create permission
```

How can I grant create permissions for clients?

Comment: Have a look to [knife-acl](https://github.com/chef/knife-acl) the web-ui does not implement configuring acl on clients container.

Comment: @Tensibai thanks a lot! Missed it somehow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to edit the ACLs directly via either the knife-acl plugin or `knife edit .../_acl.json`. The UI hides some permissions stuff to avoid being over-complicated.

Refer to: https://github.com/chef/knife-acl

Answer (score 5):

The knife-acl gem is the right answer. Specific to the OP's question, granting the ability to create clients as a member of the "provisioners" group.

```
knife acl add group provisioners containers clients create
```

I found I needed to do this for the "users" group on a brand new installation of chef-server. It doesn't seem like the out-of-box permissions really take validator-less into account.